# Where did all the Tribbles go?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

At the end of [Trials and Tribble-Ations](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Trials_and_Tribble-ations_%28episode%29), we see the whole station swarming with the Tribbles brought back from DS9's excursion to the past episode [The Trouble With Tribbles](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Trouble_with_Tribbles_%28episode%29).

Everyone, short of Klingons, love Tribbles, and wouldn't dream of sending them out into space or, dare I say, blowing one up to assassinate Captain Kirk.

Yet by the next episode, they're all gone.  And I sincerely doubt Worf could have convinced the entire crew to begin a Mass Tribble Hunt, no matter how blood-sworn Klingons may be against such cuddly creatures.

So, where did they go?  Do any expanded universe books detail the mass migration of Tribbles off of DS9, or did Worf really devour them all in his raw Klingon rage?

Comment: They were transported to Klingon Bird of Prey..

Comment: @SachinShekhar *Again*?

Comment: To steal from Scotty; where ever they went, I'm sure they were no tribble at all.

Comment: The crew ate very well for the next couple of days.

Comment: @SystemDown For days? Tribbles are born pregnant! You can eat decades from them... Which makes me think: What do tribbles eat anyway? Granted: They are mostly just fur, but even fur must come from somewhere... Can you starve them to death? What would you have to take away from them to accomplish that? Is it that what they did on DS9? It would be the most "humane" thing to do...

Comment: @Einer From conjecture, anything.  From canon, at least three things: Blue Enriched Multigrain, a Chicken Sandwich, and Coffee.

Comment: So it's solved: Seal the sections, remove all food, wait and give the remains to the Bajoran orphans - they deserve a little fury friend! And if it starts smelling funny, they can make a blanket from it. If Dukat were still in command, that's what he would do. The ol' chap had a heart of gold!

Comment: @Einer YOU try keeping a tribble away from food. See how well you do.

Comment: @Einer Tribbles eat rice. It has been shown in TOS.

Comment: @SachinShekhar The question asks about the DS9 episode.  You're referring to the TOS episode when you say Scotty beamed them to the Klingon bird of prey.  Also, the TOS episode had the tribbles devouring quadrotriticale (a hybrid of wheat and rye).  Don't recall anything in the TOS episode on them eating rice.

Comment: Oh come on people, keep up the traditions around here. *Long time passing...*

Comment: @Stan: Sachin never said *Scotty* beamed them to a Klingon Bird of Prey.

Comment: @PaulDWaite You're correct. Guess I inferred something I shouldn't have because of his subsequent TOS comment. Assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that he was also referring to the TOS episode in the 'beam' comments. Mea culpa. Were they in fact beamed to a Bird of Prey in the DS9 episode ?

Comment: @Stan: [according to the comics, no](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/55813/440)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Within the TV series itself, there's no further mention of the tribbles or their fate.

There are, however a couple of EU sources that may shed some light;

According to the DS9 Comic "[Nobody Knows the tribbles I've seen](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Nobody_Knows_the_Tribbles_I%27ve_Seen)", **the maintenance crews collected them all up and then beamed them into space**. Quark also claims that Worf went on a mad rampage with a phaser rifle (on the promenade, no less) but nobody believes him.

[image: DS9 #014]

Within the wider trek EU canon, we see that several of the tribbles escaped from the station and made their way to various Bajoran colonies (and eventually Bajor) in the story from "The Tribbles' Pagh" from [Strange New Worlds IX](http://files.novanet.org/eBooks/Star%20Trek/Other%20Collections/SNW%20-%20009%20-%20Book%20IX.txt)

After threatening to cause another famine in Tozhat province. The
Bajorans plan to kill them with "disposal units" until Doctor Bashir manages to 
synthesise a virus that limits their reproductive cycle.

> Kira took a deep breath. “Bad. Dax says that there are at least a
>   hundred thousand tribbles in the Tozhat Province. If they reproduce
>   unchecked we’re looking at over a million within twenty-four hours.
>   Trillions within a week.”
>
> “I remember,” Sisko said gravely. “I thought the station quarantine
>   was effective.”
>
> Kira gave a short barking laugh. “It wasn’t. Shakaar has instituted a
>   quarantine of Tozhat. We’re trying to track down anyone who entered
>   the province in the last two days. All shipments of salom grass are
>   being screened for tribbles. Elimination is a problem. We could use
>   some industrial disposal units.”

Comment: Beam them into space?  I mean I know they did that to the one, but it had a BOMB in it.  I guess, at least, it's a fate better than being stranded on a ship full of their most fearsome foes.  And I don't think I'll find a better answer than this either...

Comment: @Zibbobz - Beaming someone into space (in an unconfined matter stream) would be an instant and totally painless death

Comment: That's arguable...but this really isn't the place to argue the humanity of their methods.

Comment: @Richard why would it be painless?

Comment: @JMFB - Because they wouldn't regain consciousness after having been particalised.